# Extracting numbers with REGEXEXTRACT that might have a comma or dot

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of numbers in a few formats that may or may not include a dot and a comma. The numbers are locked in a string. For example:

hello 1,000 goodbye

hola 2,000.12 ciao

Hallo 3000.00 Auf Wiedersehen

How can I extract the numbers?
I don't care if the comma is added but the dot is obviously important.
I need the regular_expression to be used in REGEXEXTRACT (and the rest of the REGEX formulas.
The output should be:

1000

2000.12

3000.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your raw data is in A2:A, use this in B2 (or the second cell) of an otherwise empty column:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\d[\d,\.]*\d")))))`

The REGEX portion reads, in plain English, "Extract any portion that starts with a digit followed by any number of digits, commas or periods (or none of these) and ends with a digit."

You will likely want to apply **Format > Number > Currency** to the results column.

Comment: Great, Tom. Thanks for reporting back. BTW, if you will ever have single-digit amounts, you'll need to remove the final \d from the REGEX phrase. If you'll always have amounts of 10.00 or more, you're all set as it is.